# can i generate a htpasswd from one pc, and then ftp it to another server

Tags: apache, .htpasswd

What crypto algorithm would I use to generate the passwords within a htpasswd file?

I'm running a Visual basic program and using an ftp server to FTP up client files. Im creating new directories for each client and want to add some password protection to each clients directory (for http access).

The server runs apache on linux.
What I've read is that apache uses a slightly modified version of MD5, as well as the systems base "crypt" method. This page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html#security seems to say that I can use one of several algorithms. I guess at the moment I am confused as to how it chooses with encryption to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is chosen by the first sub-field of the password field. A typcial htpasswd file entry looks like this:

`ralph:$1$abcd1234$Kx528z52Ohx1JLSzliZmw0`

By field:

`ralph` is the user name

`1` is the hash algorithm identifier. 1=md5, 5=sha-256, 6=sha-512

`abcd1234` is the salt (not very salty here, usually generated via some pseudo-random technique)

`Kx528z52Ohx1JLSzliZmw0` is the hash.

A one-line python command to create the hash using the password and salt as inputs is:

`python -c "import crypt, getpass, pwd; print crypt.crypt('password', '\$1\$abcd1234\$')"`

DISCLAIMER: This answer largely lifted from `slm` on another forum after <5 minutes of research.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's possible. Apache can recognise different encryptions by the salt that preceeds it